# PostgreSQL - Create second by second View

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I have a table, called `tb_records` which is a record of occurences. The sample values are:

```
id  from        to
1   01:00:00    01:00:03
2   01:00:05    01:00:07
3   01:00:50    01:00:51
```

What I would like to do is to generate the second by second sequence in PostgreSQL. So the result would be

```
id  from        to          time
1   01:00:00    01:00:03    01:00:00
1   01:00:00    01:00:03    01:00:01
1   01:00:00    01:00:03    01:00:02
1   01:00:00    01:00:03    01:00:03
2   01:00:05    01:00:07    01:00:05
2   01:00:05    01:00:07    01:00:06
2   01:00:05    01:00:07    01:00:07
3   01:00:50    01:00:51    01:00:50
3   01:00:50    01:00:51    01:00:51
```

Usually, in Python or R, the *basic* algorithm I would choose (without using any library or package):

1. Calculate the difference of time in seconds for each `id` (`diff`)
2. For each id, replicate the rows by `diff`
3. Create the column `time` with initial values as column `from`
4. For each `id` and row, increment column `time` by one second

I am confused as to how to do it in SQL, since I am accustomed to create those steps sequentially.

Comment: The magic term is *calendar* table here: generate **all** possible values for seconds and JOIN  these to the other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, "from", "to",
generate_series(('2000-01-01 '||"from")::timestamp, ('2000-01-01 '||"to")::timestamp, '1 second'::interval)::time as res
from tb_records
order by id, res
```

`generate_series()` not works with `time` type, so I convert `time` to `timestamp`, and then extracted `time` part from generated result.

[***`SQL Fiddle Demo`***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66e50c/40)

Answer (score 1):

Use a calendar table, and join to it. (I renamed the columns; "to", "from", and "time" are all reserved words in SQL)

---

```
WITH omg AS ( -- calendar table
        SELECT generate_series( min(tfrom),max(tto),'1sec'::interval) AS ttick
                 FROM fromto t
        )
SELECT t.id, t.tfrom, t.tto
        , o.ttick
FROM fromto t
JOIN omg o -- join it with actual table
        ON t.tfrom <= o.ttick
        AND t.tto >= o.ttick
ORDER BY o.ttick
        ;
```

---

Or use a recursive CTE:

---

```
WITH RECURSIVE wtf AS (
        SELECT t.id, t.tfrom, t.tto
                , t.tfrom AS ttick      -- pick the lower bound
        FROM fromto t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT w.id, w.tfrom, w.tto
                , (w.ttick+ '1sec'::interval) AS ttick -- add one second
        FROM wtf w
        WHERE w.ttick < w.tto           -- if below the upper bound
        )
SELECT * FROM wtf
        ;
```